# How to display all columns in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Just edit the file below：

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
```

compare your file content with the lines below, just add the missing lines or copy all the codes below to your file(**Most importantly, make sure there is not any space at the end of each line**):

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.adbDebugBasePort=8600
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.info=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.name=94
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.permissions=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.size=44
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.time=34
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
devicePanel.Col0=319
devicePanel.Col1=38
devicePanel.Col4=61
eclipse.preferences.version=1
emulatorControl.track.name=155
emulatorControl.waypoint.name=95
heapPanel.col0=1276
logcat.view.colsize.Application=133
logcat.view.colsize.Level=44
logcat.view.colsize.PID=44
logcat.view.colsize.TID=44
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=98
logcat.view.colsize.Text=712
logcat.view.colsize.Time=131
logcat.view.filters.list=name\: 'com.android.settings', tag\: '', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: 'com.android.settings', level\: 'verbose', name\: 'ActivityManager', tag\: 'ActivityManager', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: '', level\: 'verbose',
logcat.view.font=1|Sans|11.0|0|GTK|1|;
threadPanel.Col0=24
threadPanel.Col1=37
threadPanel.Col2=61
threadPanel.Col3=34
threadPanel.Col4=34
threadPanel.Col5=272
threadPanel.stack.col0=503
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the file below：

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
```

compare your file content with the lines below, just add the missing lines or copy all the codes below to your file(**Most importantly, make sure there is not any space at the end of each line**):

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.adbDebugBasePort=8600
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.info=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.name=94
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.permissions=68
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.size=44
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.explorer.time=34
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
devicePanel.Col0=319
devicePanel.Col1=38
devicePanel.Col4=61
eclipse.preferences.version=1
emulatorControl.track.name=155
emulatorControl.waypoint.name=95
heapPanel.col0=1276
logcat.view.colsize.Application=133
logcat.view.colsize.Level=44
logcat.view.colsize.PID=44
logcat.view.colsize.TID=44
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=98
logcat.view.colsize.Text=712
logcat.view.colsize.Time=131
logcat.view.filters.list=name\: 'com.android.settings', tag\: '', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: 'com.android.settings', level\: 'verbose', name\: 'ActivityManager', tag\: 'ActivityManager', text\: '', pid\: '', app\: '', level\: 'verbose',
logcat.view.font=1|Sans|11.0|0|GTK|1|;
threadPanel.Col0=24
threadPanel.Col1=37
threadPanel.Col2=61
threadPanel.Col3=34
threadPanel.Col4=34
threadPanel.Col5=272
threadPanel.stack.col0=503
```